# In MySQL, how do you CAST a VARCHAR to UNSIGNED in a JSON_OBJECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, casting

Assuming a table with two columns, `A` and `B`, both of type VARCHAR:

```
|------------|-------------|
|      A     |     B       |
|------------|-------------|
|  EMPLOYEE  |    34       |
|------------|-------------|
|   OTHER    |  mystring   |
|------------|-------------|
```

I want column B as a JSON_OBJECT. If column A has value 'EMPLOYEE', I want to cast the value in column B to an integer. This is what that query looks like:

```
SELECT A, 
JSON_OBJECT(
   'key', IF(A = 'EMPLOYEE', CAST(B AS UNSIGNED), B)
) as B
FROM table
```

result:

```
|------------|----------------------|
|      A     |          B           |
|------------|----------------------|
|  EMPLOYEE  |    {"key": "34"}     | // Expected {"key": 34} here
|------------|----------------------|
|   OTHER    |  {"key": "mystring"} |
|------------|----------------------|
```

The problem is the cast leaves the value 34 as a string in the resulting JSON, but I want it as an integer. I have confirmed that the cast is actually running by using `TRUE` as the condition, but the json still contains a string.

One way I was able to get the cast to work was by adding `WHERE A = 'EMPLOYEE'`, but I don't know why I wouldn't be able to make the intended JSON_OBJECT without that WHERE clause. How can I get this cast working correctly?

Comment: E.g.: `CASE WHEN... THEN b = b+0 END` (not actually sure that this solves your specific issue)

Comment: @Strawberry I tried using CASE as well without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that `if()` forces a consistent datatype on the values that are returned by its two branches; same goes for most other expressions such as `case`, or functions like `coalesce()`, `least()`/`greatest()`,and so on. So implicit conversions is happening anwyay, even when you try to force two distinct datatypes.

In your use case, one solution is to move the `case` out of the `json_object()`. That way, both branches return a `json` datatype, which `if()` (or `case`) is content with:

```
select 
    a, 
    case a
        when 'EMPLOYEE' then json_object('key', cast(b as unsigned))
        else json_object('key', b)
    end b
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e79bfe3aafc7fb8f0d4415cab2177325)**:

```
a        | b                  
:------- | :------------------
EMPLOYEE | {"key": 34}        
OTHER    | {"key": "mystring"}
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL needs to know the resulting type of any expression before the query is executed. Since

```
IF(A = 'EMPLOYEE', CAST(B AS UNSIGNED), B)
```

could return either an INT or a string, the engine choose one type to return. In this case it's always a string. If you instead use this:

```
SELECT A,
  CASE WHEN A = 'EMPLOYEE'
    THEN JSON_OBJECT('key', CAST(B AS UNSIGNED))
    ELSE JSON_OBJECT('key', B)
  END as B
FROM mytable
```

`CAST(B AS UNSIGNED)` will always return an INT and `B` will be always a string. And the hole CASE expression will always return a JSON object. Then you get:

```
| A        | B                   |
| -------- | ------------------- |
| EMPLOYEE | {"key": 34}         |
| OTHER    | {"key": "mystring"} |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

This is not about CASE versus IF, and also not about how you cast. So you can also write it as

```
SELECT A,
IF(
  A = 'EMPLOYEE',
  JSON_OBJECT('key', B+0),
  JSON_OBJECT('key', B)
) as B
FROM mytable
```

and get the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've accepted the answer by @GMB because it came first (literally 7 seconds before yours!)